# 1 submit button but 2 actions to be performed based on the selection from dropdown in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need to have one submit button but it needs to perform 2 different actions based on the value selected from the dropdown.

The dropdown has values "Order","Search","Alerts".

When I select Order and then submit it should redirect the way it is i.e, submitForm () should trigger.

When I select Search and then submit it should redirect to a different return URL or return Form.

. How should I returnForm or the return URL in javascript? How do I differentiate between the click.?

The file is completely a HTML and js file

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Pls read this (and show your code plus your attempt): https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can use an event listener on the form element to listen for submit event of the form, then every time the form is submitted you can get the current value of the select element and use an if/else if statement or even a switch case (in this example I'm using if and else if statement) to call tasks based on the select element's value.

HTML:

```
<form>
    <select name="dropdown" id="dropdown">
        <option value="order">Order</option>
        <option value="search">Search</option>
        <option value="alerts">Alerts</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
const form = document.querySelector("form");
const selectElement = form.querySelector("#dropdown");

form.addEventListener("submit", (event) => {

  event.preventDefault();

  if (selectElement.value === "order") {

    // Do stuff for order
    console.log("Completed tasks for order");

  } else if (selectElement.value === "search") {

    // Do stuff for search
    console.log("Completed tasks for search");

  } else if (selectElement.value === "alerts") {

    // Do stuff for alerts
    console.log("Completed tasks for alerts");

  } else {

    console.log("Do nothing");

  }
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you can use a switch-case or just a regular if-elseif-else statement for that based on the value of the select tag